# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'funcion' was never awaited

Tags: python, asyncio

Estoy viendo la asincronicidad pero al querer ejecutarlo me dice que nunca estuvo en espera

es una llamada al api, todo bien lo probe por si solo y me trabajaba perfecto pero al querer ejecutarlo en la app me bloquea todo

async def datoSansara(self, vehiculo):
# Pasamos la URL para la busqueda con la entrada desde tkinter

```
url = "https://api.samsara.com/fleet/vehicles/locations/feed?vehicleIds=%s" % vehiculo
#url = f"{url_base}{self.name.get()}"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
endCursor = ""
querystring = {}

while True:
    if endCursor:
        querystring["after"] = endCursor
        # Obtenemos los valores del API
        executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
        response = await loop.set_default_executor(executor,requests.request(
            "GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()) 
        vehicle_location = response["data"]

        for vehicle in vehicle_location:
            #vehicle_id = vehicle["id"]
            #name = vehicle["name"]
            for location in vehicle["locations"]:
                #heading = location["heading"]
                latitud = location["latitude"]
                longitud = location["longitude"]
                velocidad = location["speed"]
                tiempo = location["time"]
                now = datetime.now()

                # Agregamos los valores a tkinter para poder examinarlos

                self.Latitud.insert(0, str(latitud))
                self.Longitud.insert(0, str(longitud))
                self.Altitud.insert(0, "1")
                self.Velocidad.insert(0, str(velocidad))
                self.FechaIni.insert(0, str(tiempo))
                self.FechaEvento.insert(0, now)

        endCursor = response["pagination"]["endCursor"]

        if response["pagination"]["endCursor"]:
            break
```

y asi es como lo agrego al main

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Samsara(window)
    window.mainloop()
    asyncio.run(window.mainloop())
```

esta en la funcion donde mando llamarlo

```
def BuscarDatos(self):

        Nombre = self.name.get()

        try:
            with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
                consulta = "SELECT id_Vehiculo,NumeroSerial FROM SamsaraVehiculos WHERE Nombre=?"

                cursor.execute(consulta, (Nombre))

                _Serie = cursor.fetchall()

                for NumSerie in _Serie:
                    self.Serie.insert(0, NumSerie[1])
                    
                    id_ = NumSerie[0]

                    if (NumSerie != ""):
                        asyncio.wait(self.datoSansara(id_))
                    else:
                        messagebox.showinfo(
                            Message="Ocurrio un error al ejecutar el api", title="Error")

        except Exception as e:
            #print("Ocurrio un error al consultar: ", e)
            messagebox.showinfo(Message=e, title="Error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema es ésto:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Samsara(window)
    window.mainloop()                # <<<<<<<<<< 1º
    asyncio.run(window.mainloop())   # <<<<<<<<<< 2º
```

`asyncio.run` no llega a ejecutarse nunca, solo cuando se cierra la app. La llamada a `tkinter.Tk.mainloop` es bloqueante, en esencia es un ciclo `while` infinito que solo termina cuando la app se cierra.

Dicho ésto:

- Tkinter no está pensado para trabajar de forma conjunta con corrutinas y la programación asíncrona basada en ellas. Hay forma de hacerlo funcionar, pero generalmente creo que es mucho más simple mover todo a un hilo o proceso hijo y en él trabajar con `asyncio` si lo necesitamos.
- Igualmente, `requests` tampoco permite realizar peticiones de forma asíncrona. Hay bibliotecas explícitamente pensadas para ello que hacen uso de asyncio, una de ellas es `aiohttp`.
- Aparentemente en tu app, lo único que necesitas es que el mainloop no se bloquee, para ello un simple hilo y `requets` te vale, es mucho más simple y no ganas nada intentado unir todo con `asyncio`.

Digo "aparentemente" porque no haces peticiones simultáneas al servidor, según parece necesitas los datos de la consulta previa para hacer la siguiente. Ahora bien, si llegaras a hacer o poder hacer peticiones simultáneas al servidor, decenas, cientos o miles, el uso de frameworks pensados para ello ocasiona generalmente resultados extremadamente sorprendentes con respecto a uso de `requests`, por ejemplo [aiohttp](/questions/tagged/aiohttp) es capaz de hacer en torno a 6000-7000 peticiones por segundo y hay frameworks capaces de bastante más, generalmente no es necesario tanto, llegar a éstos límites en condiciones normales suele terminar con conexiones cerradas o el servidor mandándote a paseo por estar abusando...

El scraping con bs4 no es un problema de IO, sino de CPU. Por tanto no abordable con hilos (sin liberar el GIL) o corrutinas, si llegara a ser un problema, que lo dudo, ésto hay que resolverlo mediante subprocesos.

En principio, por tanto, yo usaría un hilo sin más. Eso si, ten en cuenta:

- No se debe jamás interactuar con la app desde un hilo o proceso distinto al principal. Ésto es común a muchos frameworks gráficos y se suele derivar de que las APIs de bajo nivel usadas como OpenGl no permiten realizar operaciones desde otro hilo de forma segura.
- Debes sincronizar y pasar la información entre ambos hilos de forma segura para evitar condiciones de carrera. Comúnmente se usa una simple cola y el hilo principal actúa de mero consumidor usando `after` para hacer comprobaciones periódicas del contenido de la cola y actualizando la interfaz en base a ello.

Dado que la API no es abierta te dejo un ejemplo que puedas adaptar usando un hilo y una cola, simplemente obtiene las preguntas más nuevas con etiqueta Python del propio [so.es] y las muestra en un widget `Text` listadas.

```
import queue
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.resultados = ScrolledText(self)
        self.resultados.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        self.consulta_btn = tk.Button(
            self, text='Consultar', command=self.obtener_preguntas
            )
        self.consulta_btn.pack(expand=True, fill="x")
    
    def obtener_preguntas(self):
        self.resultados.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.consulta_btn.config(
            text="Realizando consulta, espere...", state="disabled"
            )
        self._que = queue.Queue()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._make_request, args=(self._que, ))
        thread.start()
        self._get_results()
    
    @staticmethod
    def _make_request(que):
        req = requests.get(
            "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=Newest"
            )
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
        preguntas = [
            tag.text.strip() for tag in soup.find_all(
                "a", class_="question-hyperlink"
                )]
        for pregunta in preguntas:
            que.put(pregunta)
        que.put("<<Done>>") # Señal para indicar que hemos terminado
        
    def _get_results(self):
        try:
            data = self._que.get(0)
        except queue.Empty:
            self.after(500, self._get_results)
        else:
            if data == "<<Done>>":
                self.consulta_btn.config(text="Consulta", state="normal")
                return
            else:
                self.resultados.insert(tk.END, f"⯁ {data}\n")
                self.after(100, self._get_results) # Comprobamos datos nuevos cada 100 ms


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que tienes un error de lógica en tu código:

```
endCursor = ""     # <<<< una cadena vacía se evalúa como False
querystring = {}

while True:
    if endCursor:  # <<<< no se ejecuta
        response = ...
        ...
    endCursor = response["pagination"]["endCursor"] # <<<< response no existe
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por explicarme, te entendi mucho mejor que todas las paginas que lei, y lo peor es que cuando vi lo facil que era me senti algo tonto xD

Gracias!!